# The tag size is not the same on all processors

Tags: bsp

ABORT(pid  1):{bsp_set_tagsize} line 136  of "BSP.cpp"
The tag size is not the same on all processors

what that mean?

`bsp_begin(bsp_nprocs());

...

bsp_push_reg(matrix,sizeof(int)*sizeMatrix*sizeMatrix);
bsp_push_reg(&answer,sizeof(int));

bsp_sync();

...

for(level=1;level<=sizeMatrix;level++){

...

}`

bsp_sync();
bsp_pop_reg(matrix);
bsp_pop_reg(&answer);
bsp_sync();
bsp_end();

in the for there no bsp_sync()
if i put the for at comment it work,
if not it say that error.

someone can explain?